# Django 2.1: Howto reset_password()

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-admin

I am new in Django.
Django version 2.1 has a deleted `reset_password()` function.
How should I add an admin page with password reset for the admin account?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.PasswordResetView

Answer (score 2):

As of django 2.1, all auth views have become class based views.
You can do password reset in this way

Instead of

> path('...'/reset_password)

Use

> path('...'/PasswordResetView.as_view(template_name="[path to template]")

This is mentioned in docs
[All Auth Views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/default/#all-authentication-views)
[Password Reset View](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.PasswordResetView)